# impact of large number of source code files on compilation performance

Tags: scala

I've a set of related scala case classes in each file as below:
eg.

```
case class Book(pages: Seq[Page]);
case class Page(paras: Seq[Para]);
case class Para(lines: Seq[Line]);
case class Line(words: Seq[String]);
...
```

I've about 100 such files with each file containing a group of related case classes. The problem I see with this is that, some files grow very big to the extent of 500-1000 lines of code. My IDE takes a long to time to compile such large files and hangs at times, while editing such files. When I raise a PR, Github is not happy to render such large files' diff by default.

So, I plan to split each case class into a separate file, sticking to the rule of "1-class per file". The side effect of this is that now there could 1000s of files as I've a lot of such case classes.

Here is the question:
Does switching from "small number(few 100s) of big files" approach to a "large number(1000s) of small files" approach have a negative impact on compilation performance? Could the increase in the number of files cause scala compiler to take a considerably long time to read all these files and compile? OR Could the decrease in file line count due to "1-class per file" approach, help the compiler perform better? 
Could there be any runtime performance difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: not sure if a clean compile takes longer or not, but using incremental compilation the compiler will check which units of compilations (files) have changed since last time and compile those, and all the files that depend on the changed files. So having 1 class per file is better from that point of view

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing compiler performance with IDE performance. Try closing your IDE and compile the project from the command line using sbt/gradle/maven. I believe it will be reasonably fast.
In scala compiler performance could be ruined by a combination of implicits and type inference. Few thousand lines of plain class declarations shouldn't be a problem no matter how you split it. So you should choose what works best for you tools. Or maybe rethink application design.

Runtime performance will not change at all.